# Tab completion not seeing my modules in IPython 0.12

Tags: python, macos, ipython, tab-completion, enthought

IPython is not able to tab-complete the names of modules in the current directory when importing.

If I have a file called Blah.py in the current directory I would like to type (at an ipython prompt)
import Bl
and have it complete to "import Blah". It seems like nothing happens when I press tab though. Tab completion in other contexts seems to work fine.

I am using EPD 7.2-2 64bit on Mac OSX version 10.5.8. It comes with IPython version 0.12.

This kind of tab completion used to work for me with IPython version 0.10.2 on a Mac (though it wasn't part of EPD). The only other difference I notice in this EPD version is that tab completion also closes the quotes every time you tab-complete a directory name within a string.

Any ideas are appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: If you run `%rehashx`, does that sort it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in `sys.path`. The first entry was an empty string `''`. I guess the completer doesn't understand that this means to look in the current directory (maybe it understood in previous versions?). If you add `'./'` to the path then everything works fine.

At the beginning my ipython_config.py file I just added

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, './')
```

That solves the problem permanently.

Answer (score 0):

Have you got readline installed ?

```
pip install readline
```

Comment: The other tab completion features seem to be already working. I did try installing readline with pip but it did not solve the problem.

Actually, the pip readline introduced a new problem. When the tab-completion possibilities were very long (e.g. `sys.<TAB>`) they would scroll off the top of the terminal window and did not seem to go through the "pager".